# DB Error: constraint violation on anonymous user event registration after 5.8.2 -> 5.9.0 update

Tags: error, database

After updating from 5.8.2 to 5.9.0, anonymous users suddenly get the above error when trying to register for an event.

Anyone a good hint how to resolve that? Thanks

Debug log shows

Datenbank-Errorcode: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_local`.`civicrm_acl_contact_cache`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), 1452
Zusätzliche Details:

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

```
[code] => -3
[message] => DB Error: constraint violation
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_acl_contact_cache ( user_id, contact_id, operation ) VALUES(0, 0, 'View') [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_local`.`civicrm_acl_contact_cache`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_acl_contact_cache ( user_id, contact_id, operation ) VALUES(0, 0, 'View') [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_local`.`civicrm_acl_contact_cache`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: constraint violation" code=-3 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_acl_contact_cache ( user_id, contact_id, operation ) VALUES(0, 0, 'View') [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_local`.`civicrm_acl_contact_cache`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]"]
```

)

Comment: Are you able to replicate this issue on a [sandbox site](https://civicrm.org/sandboxes)?

Comment: Do you have ACL enabled on site?

Comment: I use only the Wordpress permission management and have no further ACL enabled.

Comment: I have the same problem with 5.8.x to 5.9 upgrade on a contribution page for anon users (Joomla). Error: Database Error Code: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zzz`.`civicrm_acl_contact_cache`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), 1452
Additional Details: Array
( [callback] => Array ( [0] => CRM_Core_Error [1] => handle ) [code] => -3 [message] => DB Error: constraint violation [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_acl_contact_cache ( user_id, contact_id, ope

Answer (score 2):

I could solve the problem... I had disabled the Mail module of CiviCRM as I do yet not use it. After reenabling it, the error was gone. Looks like that even disabled modules leave remnants in the database causing possible trouble.

Answer (score 2):

This pull request seems relevant to the database error you encountered: [(dev/core#660) Address regression whereby Anonymous users can no longer register for an event if they have ACLs to see a contact](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13451). This fixes an issue that was I believe introduced in Civi 5.9.0 and fixed in 5.9.1 .

See also related issue [Fatal DB Error: already exists on event registration/contribution pages when profile has user creation](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/660).

Comment: These issues are cousins - but one affects the `civicrm_uf_match` table, the other affects `civicrm_acl_contact_cache`.  My answer below addresses it.

Answer (score 0):

We recently upgraded a CiviCRM installation from 4.6 to 5.9.0 and encountered the same issue when trying to register for a membership (contribution page) as anonymous user.

Disabling/enabling the CiviCRM Mail Component didn't fix this.

I removed the foreign keys in the database as a temporary fix:

`alter table civicrm_acl_contact_cache drop foreign key FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_user_id`
`alter table civicrm_acl_contact_cache drop foreign key FK_civicrm_acl_contact_cache_contact_id`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when I had a particular customization in place, but it revealed what I think is the core issue.

This error occurs when you have "view my contact" and/or "edit my contact" permission on the anonymous user - who, by definition, does not have a contact.

I'm submitting a patch, so hopefully this is a non-issue in CiviCRM 5.70+ or so, but you can fix it now by changing your CMS's user permissions.